# Does the SharePoint Search crawler execute JavaScript?

Tags: 2013, search, crawling, crawl

The content of many web sites is being rendered with the usage of JavaScript after the page has been loaded on client side. Modern search crawlers like Google execute those scripts and index the updated DOM.

Does the SharePoint Search crawler the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it does not. You can watch how the crawler works against a web site by using Fiddler as a proxy for the crawler.

Comment: Yes it's true. I ran a crawl against an Angular website and used Fiddler as a proxy. SharePoint just crawls the initial markup. JavaScript is not recognized any further.

Is the SharePoint team planning to implement such a functionality in the future? Any info on that?

Comment: I couldn't say what they are planning.